# django rest action got unexpected positional argument

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have an viewset with action, which has defined for adding friends to user. But I got a problem with url, send post query on http://localhost:8000/accounts/users/mercer/add_friend/
and got this message: **add_friend() got an unexpected keyword argument 'username'**

My ViewSet:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = CustomUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    lookup_field = 'username'
    http_method_names = ['get', 'patch', 'post']

    @action(detail=True, methods=['post'])
    def add_friend(self, request):
        return Response('ok')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Django Viewsets documentation on marking extra actions for routing](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing):

> Like regular actions, extra actions may be intended for either a single object, or an entire collection. To indicate this, set the detail argument to True or False. The router will configure its URL patterns accordingly. e.g., the DefaultRouter will configure detail actions to contain pk in their URL patterns.

As you declared `detail=True`, you're indicating this action will be applied in a `CustomUser` object instead of all your users. I think you've got this in your post url, as you seem to be passing *"mercer"* as your object username. Thus, you also have to expect `username` to be passed as an argument in your action method:

```
@action(detail=True, methods=['post'])
def add_friend(self, request, username=None):
    # your code
    return Response('ok')
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I was trying to do that a while ago, and got another error: "__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given".

Comment: Are you sure you tried to do this same thing? Where was this error occuring?

Comment: Ohh, another problem was with Response(). I have imported it from this:"from requests import Response" not from "from rest_framework.response import Response" . Thanks, you solved my problem